# fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.Internal.DefaultAntiforgery

Tags: c#, identityserver4, antiforgerytoken, linux-containers

I have 4 docker container in a yml file.

1. Db container
2. Identity Server Container (asp.net core application with identity server)
3. Api Server (asp.net core application)
4. Client (Angular 9 app)

Everything works well on development windows machine and I deployed it on one of client on his windows server and I hosted all application on IIS with 3 different sites on IIS and a separate database.

Now, what I want is to deploy it on linux docker container, overall configuration works well, though need improvements(which I can do) but I am stuck at the following error, and with docker logs on Identity server container it show following error

> fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.Internal.DefaultAntiforgery[7]
>         An exception was thrown while deserializing the token. Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.AntiforgeryValidationException: The
>   antiforgery token could not be decrypted. --->
>   System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: The key
>   {d7972341-6e64-467d-af09-124f5ba3e3a8} was not found in the key ring. 
>   at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.KeyRingBasedDataProtector.UnprotectCore(Byte[]
>   protectedData, Boolean allowOperationsOnRevokedKeys, UnprotectStatus&
>   status)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.KeyRingBasedDataProtector.DangerousUnprotect(Byte[]
>   protectedData, Boolean ignoreRevocationErrors, Boolean&
>   requiresMigration, Boolean& wasRevoked)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.KeyRingBasedDataProtector.Unprotect(Byte[]
>   protectedData)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.Internal.DefaultAntiforgeryTokenSerializer.Deserialize(String
>   serializedToken)    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.Internal.DefaultAntiforgeryTokenSerializer.Deserialize(String
>   serializedToken)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.Internal.DefaultAntiforgery.GetCookieTokenDoesNotThrow(HttpContext
>   httpContext)

Remember I am using a pfx file for certificate on Identity Server container.

I just don't understand where this key issue is coming and where this key is not found in the key ring ?

Any help or discussion would be highly appreciated.

After success, I want to deploy it either on Digital Ocean

Comment: Perhaps this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42103004/using-antiforgery-in-asp-net-core-and-got-error-the-antiforgery-token-could-no#47143941

Comment: yes, I went through that before and that code is present in startup.cs file as well.

Answer (score 2):

After again through research and different solution, got one solution seems to work somewhat.
The solution from this post 
https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/3540
by StefanoChiodino works well so far.

What I have done is to just recreate all containers with all different ports binding and yes it works and generates proper keys that can be decrypted by Identity Server.

Comment: Load User Profile = true worked for me from that post

Answer (score 0):

This error arises when the presented anti-forgery token is not on the persisted grants of the application.
Are you implement the IPersistedGrant interface or are you saving that information in-memory? This errors were presented after a release or on rebooting the server?

A common reason is having this information in-memory and rebooting the server.

Another reason is deleting the information on the dbo."PersistedGrants" database.

If you have implemented the IPersistedGrants interface, do you have multiple instances of that database?

I hope this helps you!

Answer (score 0):

You should do 2 thing to fix it:

1. Run your applicattion on port 443
2. Set the variable ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT: "Development"

Thats how dockercompose & dockerfile file should be:
[image: Docker file]
[image: Docker Compose]

It worked for me .

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same error, I fixed it by deleting the entire browser cache and adding this line to Program
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jtg9L.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1TWqW.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ixlt6.png)

Comment: Do not add images from other resources for prevent missing them at future.